# If statement and addition

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to look if a cell value in second sheet is not equal to blank and then check the value of other cell is lesser than 3 and further update the value to 1 or 0.

1st condition if g2 cell value present in second sheet is not equal to blank then check for f5 cell value. If the f5 cell value is less than 3 than it should display as 1 else 0

```
=sheet2!NOT(ISBLANK($G2)) + IF($F5>2, 0, 1)
```

Thanks

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: There are 2 conditions : 1st to check the cell value in sheet2 is not blank . 2nd cond to check if the cell value f5 in sheet2 is less than 3 than put value as 1 else 0 in sheet1 cell. so both the conditions should get satisfy. Hope I am able to explain it now

Comment: 1st condition if g2 cell value present in second sheet is not equal to blank then check for f5 cell value. If the f5 cell value is less than 3 than it should display as 1 else 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your formula `=sheet2!NOT(ISBLANK($G2)) + IF($F5>2, 0, 1)` is not using proper Excel syntax. The sheet reference goes with the cell reference, not outside the general formula. Also, your formula checks if `F5` is greater than 2, not less than 3.

> There are 2 conditions : 1st to check the cell value in sheet2 is not blank.

`NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet2!$G2))` checks this.

> 2nd cond to check if the cell value f5 in sheet2 is less than 3

The logical condition `$F5 < 3` checks this.

> than put value as 1 else 0 in sheet1 cell.

`IF(condition(s), 1, 0)`

> so both the conditions should get satisfy.

Now you want to check that *both* conditions are met, so you need an `AND()` function in your `IF()` function's logical test argument: `=IF(AND(), 1, 0)`

Or to put it together: `IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(sheet2!$G2)), $F5 < 3), 1, 0)`

Comment: This is a very good write up. This question gets right to the heart of Boolean logic and `AND` vs `OR`. OP is wading dangerously close to `OR` with that plus sign which is not the desired result. The correct result could also be obtained by multiplying the conditions together since Multiplication of boolean expressions results in an `AND`: `ISBLANK(Sheet2!$G2) * ($F3 < 3)` will yeild a `TRUE` or `FALSE` result.

Comment: @JNevill: Yes, this is a good point. An alternate approach to obtain the desired `{0,1}` output would be to simply obtain the `TRUE` or `FALSE` result and then multiply by `1` rather than use the `IF()` function: _e.g._, `=(NOT(ISBLANK(sheet2!$G2)) * ($F5 < 3)) * 1`